# select X amount of points from a dataset

Tags: php, formatting, dataset, logic, modulus

I would like to always select 30 points from a dataset

the dataset may have 30 points or it may have 5 points or it may have 100+ points.

What would be the logic for this, I want a resulting array to only have 40 datapoints

I was considering doing some kind of modulus arithmetic , like `if X mod 30 == 0 , push X to array`

but I didn't think it factored in all of my conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about an array and want to pick 30 values from it then you can do something like that:

```
$array = range(0, 4);
$start = 0;
$count = 30;
$infinite = new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($array));
$limit = new LimitIterator($infinite, $start, $count);

$result = array();

foreach ($limit as $value) {
    $result[] = $value;
}

print_r($result);
```

The `$result` array will always contain 30 elements no matter how many elements `$array` contains. If `$array` contains less than 30 values it will wrap around.

Comment: okay, I don't want it to wrap around, I am using this dataset for a chart that always need to be in chronological order

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you need. So what should happen if the array contains less then 30 values?

Comment: I can do a condition for less than 30 values in the dataset, I suppose